# Where is the condition of infinite cyclic being used?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

While reading Munkres' Topology, I came across this lemma.

> Let $G$ is a free abelian group with basis $\{g_{\alpha}\}$. If $H$ is any other abelian group and if $\{y_{\alpha}\}$ is a family of elements of $H$, then there is a homomorphism $h:G\rightarrow H$ such that $h(g_{\alpha})=y_{\alpha}$.

In the definition of free abelian group, we require that $G$ is the direct sum of the subgroups $G_{\alpha}=\langle g_{\alpha}\rangle$, and that each $G_{\alpha}$ is an infinite cyclic group. Coming back to the lemma, we can simply define $h(ng_{\alpha})=ny_{\alpha}$, where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Why do we need the fact that the subgroup $G_{\alpha}$ is an *infinite* cyclic group for defining this homomorphism?

Comment: Oh. Thanks. I see now. Would you mind writing that as an answer (not the complete proof), so that I can accept the answer?

Comment: I want to keep my $1337$ answer tally for the time being. Will post under different account.

Comment: Interesting. 1337 does make sense to keep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a homomorphism $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$ sending $1\mapsto1$?

An element of order $n$ under a group homomorphism is sent to an element of order dividing $n$, so there are restrictions on where it can be sent. In order to remove these restrictions, $G$ must be free, so it cannot contain elements of finite order.